# Using a macro to replace "using namespace ...;"

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces

The question I have is related to style in C++, and is an issue I'm currently debating with in my own library.
Consider the following example:

Under library convention, everything in the library is encased in a namespace with the name of the library. Suppose it's `lib`. Now, suppose that we have a module within that library which has its own namespace and a series of classes:

```
namespace lib
{
    namespace a
    {
        class X;
        class Y;
        class Z;
    }
 }
```

Now normally if I want to access class `X`, I would have to type `lib::a::X`, but this gets tedious after a while. Since I try to keep namespaces as local as possible, I usually put `using namespace lib::a;` at the top of the function where I'm using the members of namespace `a`. The question I have is this: say instead of having to type `using namespace lib::a;` I defined a macro in a header as follows:

```
#define USING_LIB_A_NS using namespace lib::a
```

I can then just use this macro instead. Are there any potential issues that could arise from using this? As of yet I haven't found any, but I am curious to see if there are any potential problems.

Comment: What benefit could this possibly have over using the `using` directive explicitly?

Comment: What's the point? The macro is maybe 10 characters shorter - is it really that onerous to type (or, more likely, copy/paste) extra 10 characters per file?

Comment: Also, consider doing `using lib::a::X;` instead of `using` the whole namespace.

Comment: @user2357112 The answer to your first question is: there isn't one. I saw a similar use of macros for namespaces in another library and I thought it was a good idea. I was just curious as to whether there were any dangers. As for your second comment, at the time I did this, I wasn't aware that you could do that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern IDEs provide you with autofill and code snippets and all kind of trinkets to reduce tedious repetative typing. Now when you (or someone else) get to read the code, the ugliness reverses: what took little time to type can take a lot to read and understand. So if the only goal of using a macro is to reduce your keyboard activity, I suggest defining a code snippet in your IDE instead.

This being said, I see no actual danger of this macro breaking your code behaviour or something like that - it's just a question of style.

Comment: thank you for the response. I agree with your comment about macros (I avoid them as much as possible) but at the time I started writing this I was a newbie and had lots of ideas and this seemed like a good one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

```
namespace la=lib::a;

la::X x; // short, sweet and safe
```

represents a good compromise between the amount you type and the safety of still using namespace qualification (thus avoid naming collision).

<sup>E.g. it's quite easy to forget that `std` defines `left` and `right`, and those are oh-so-tempting-names to use for members/functions especially if you are coding a binary tree (this is why `using namespace std;` is so much frown upon).</sup>

Given you are building a library, as the complexity increases, the 'common domain-specific terminology' will create chances for collisions *with your own terms* - otherwise why the need of discriminating between `lib::a` and `lib::b`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm aware now (after lots of reading) that you can do that, but at the time I started I wasn't. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using

```
#define USING_LIB_A_NS using namespace lib::a
```

In your code, use of

```
USING_LIB_A_NS;
```

is not a whole lot different than use of

```
using namespace lib::a;
```

The latter is clearer and is preferable.

Use of macros in C++ is worthwhile only if they streamline creation of a whole lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do define that marco and then use it is the same as if you just typed "using namespace".

When you go to compile your program there is a pre-processing step where a [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) will just to textual substitution i.e just replace the marco with the text.

so if you had code like

```
#define PLUSFIVE(x) (x+5)

int main(int argv, char** argc){

    std::cout << PLUSFIVE(4) << std::endl;
}
```

after the preprocessing step it would look like

```
int main(int argv, char** argc){

    std::cout << 4+5 << std::endl;
}
```

so in short there is no difference.